# Device Image download Issue

Tags: ios

when i load collectionView, that display two columns. Column inside image and details.
Simulator work perfect but when I run through in device app. is crash
I don’t know what has the wrong 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enWVI.png)

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Comment: clean project and run again

Comment: it is not for crash app but it displayed something wrong while build your project.

Comment: Just fix the syntax and grammar

Comment: can you try a different cable? the error is showing that the ipod is being disconnected.

Comment: may be that is cash memory issue .